# Updating core data entity with observedobject

Tags: core-data, swiftui, observedobject

I have created a list of clients which get saved in core data. I added some attributes through an AddView and now I am trying to add a new attribute using a different view. In order to do that I understood I need to use the observedObject property wrapper so that it doesn't create a new client but update the existing one. This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TopicView: View {


@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@ObservedObject var topic: StudentData
@State var content = ""
@State private var show = false
@StateObject private var keyboard = Keyboard()

var body: some View {
Form{
            Section (header: Text("Topics covered")
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.all)
                        .font(.title3)) {
        

TextEditor(text: Binding(
                            get: {self.topic.content ?? ""},
                            set: {self.topic.content = $0 } ))
                    .frame(height: 250)
                    
    }
                 }.onTapGesture {
                    hideKeyboard()
                }
               }
             }
             Button ("Submit")
                 {
                    self.topic.content = self.content
                    self.topic.objectWillChange.send()

                    try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
               }.foregroundColor(.white)
```

This is the view where the new attribute should be shown:

```
    import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import MapKit

struct StudentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: StudentData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [],
        animation: .spring())  var content: FetchedResults<StudentData>
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var topic: StudentData
    @State var showModalView = false
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    let myStudent: StudentData
  
var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
VStack{
                    Text("Topics Covered")
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                   Text("\(myStudent.content ?? "")")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal) }}
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
}.sheet(isPresented: $showModalView, content: {
            TopicView(topic: topic)})
```

The problem is, if I type in the texteditor some text without save it then it shows correctly in the other view. However, when I save it, it does not show in the other view.
Is there anything wrong in my save code?

Comment: Don’t create the newStudent when you submit. Just save the context

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my save button. It does not create a new client now but still when I submit it, it doesn't update the core data. Any pointers please?

Comment: What is the point of this? `let myStudent: StudentData ` if u want to see changes you have to wrap it in an `@ObservedObject `

Comment: This line clears your content self.topic.content = self.content get rid of that State variable it doesn’t do anything just work with the CoreData object

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I wasn't sure about that line but I found in another post so I thought it should be included.

Comment: Don't copy and paste other people's work. That is the worst mistake you can make starting out. If you do, you need to spend extra time learning what each line does. You will run around in circles for days if you make it a habit. Make sure you know the why of every single line. At some point you will have to explain why you chose to do something and "I copied it from somewhere" will never be a good answer.

Comment: I totally agree with you and I know it is wrong but I started to learn coding in the last two months pretty much watching videos and reading on the internet so I still struggle to understand the logic in many situations if I don't find a clear source of explanation but I am learning every day something thanks to suggestions like yours. Cheers